# How to add custombutton on Draw toolbar leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, toolbar

I want to add custom button on Draw toolbar where I need to add my own functionality .

I have wrote my code as :

```
 var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
      draw: {
          marker: false,
          rectangle: false,
          circle: {
            shapeOptions: {
              color: '#00FF00'
            }
          },
          polyline: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#FF0000',
                weight: 5
            }
          },
          polygon : {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#0000FF',
                weight: 10
            }
          },

      },
      edit: {
        featureGroup: this.drawnItems, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: false
    }
    });

 this.map.addControl(drawControl)
```

And i found online that this will help me to create custom button. but it throwing an error:

```
map.Toolbar.createCustomControl({
      name: 'CustomButton',
      block: 'draw',
      className: 'control-icon leaflet-pm-icon-marker',
      actions: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        onClick: onclick
      }]
    })
```

Error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createCustomControl')

What might cause this error?

Comment: Please edit your question and add actual reference for "I found online".